# python: To display a youtube video in the mac terminal

Tags: python, video, terminal, display

I know how to use IPython to embed a YouTube video in the notebook.

from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
 YouTubeVideo('1j_HxD4iLn8')

See live example here:   http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb#Video

but when I'm running the code in the mac terminal it isn't displaying in the terminal. Please see the image below.

I want to display the video by the terminal or display it in a new window. Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

[image: Display the youtube video on the terminal]

Comment: Please the following link that displaying the youtube video 
See live example here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb#Video

Answer (score 1):

IPython.display will only work inside IPython which you are currently not using.

Comment: I am a new one to python, could you tell me what's your mean in detail or how to solve it, thanks!

Comment: @KeTian You may add `from IPython import embed; embed()` before the other imports.

Comment: I follow what your mentioned, but there is the same issue. please see the image.  I may miss something, please help me check it in detail!                           >>> from IPython import embed
>>> from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
>>> YouTubeVideo('1j_HxD4iLn8')
<IPython.lib.display.YouTubeVideo object at 0x1021e1a50>
>>> ›